# NHibernate SqlQuery - Retrieve column names from empty result set

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a way to retrieve the column names from the sql query, when there are no results?
For example:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("select 'test' as '1' where 1=0")
```

I'd like to get the column name '1'.

I've tried using all the built-in transformers and wrote a custom transformer, but TransformTuple is not called and TransformList is called with an empty collection.

Is there a way I can get the columns?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger - I need the columns so I could export the results into csv. And I don't know the columns in advance so I can't do that easily.

Comment: How can you express a query (other than select *) when you don't know the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. Keep in mind that NHibernate is a ORM, not a general purpose SQL executor. You can get the inner DbConnection from the ISession and use the ExecuteReader method to get a DbDataReader, from which you can get the schema.